# How to encrypt and decrypt using ECDSA private key and public key generated in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, encryption, hyperledger-fabric, digital-signature, ecdsa

I am working on a basic-network project on **Hyperledeger Fabric V-1.4.1**. I have enrolled an admin and created a user using **enrollAdmin.js** and **registerUser.js**. A **public Key** and a **private key** is generated for **user1**. Now I want to use that **private key** to **sign** simple data and later **verify** using the **public Key**. I have tried using **URSA** node module which works fine with RSA keys generated through **OpenSSL** but isn't working with these two keys. Probably because these keys are not **RSA**, they are **ECDSA** keys. I have also read the documentation of the **Crypto** node module and it seems I need to have **.pem** files as keys to use in **Crypto** module. But In fabric, I have key files as **-priv** and **-pub** format.

Is there any node module that can encrypt decrypt using **ECDSA** keys?

Is there any specific way in hyperledger fabric to do this?

Or is there any other way I can do this thing?
 Please ask any questions if necessary.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two formats you see

- priv
- pub

Are wallet formate of filestorage

Try to register an identity and enroll with fabric-CA by importing identity service then you will receive certificate and private key just put it in a file and mark the extension as pem and it will work

Comment: I tried the steps you have mentioned but getting the Error: error:0608B096:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init:operation not supported for this keytype, can you suggest which cryptography technique I have to use?